# How can I load images to memory before displaying on p5.js/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, p5.js

I have written some code to display images very quickly in succession, however, there are often gaps in between when images are loaded which is extremely jarring. I would be curious as to how I could get rid of these large gaps. I have about 1000 images so I am attempting to make this code as non-tedious as possible. My current thought would be to somehow load them to memory first using p5.js. Anything helps!

```
let faces = [];
let i = 0

function preload(){
    window.onload = setInterval(() => {
        i++
        if(i > 999){
            i = 0;
        } 
        faces[i] = loadImage(`aberdeen_results/${i}.jpg`)
    }, 400);
}


function setup(){
    createCanvas(innerWidth,innerHeight); 
}

function draw(){
    background(256)
    image(faces[i], 450, 150,);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if this image fills entire screen you can use

```
background(faces[i]);
```

and it gives way less lag, maybe it would help.

Answer (score 0):

There were some flaws with your code, since it was giving errors on my side.

You need not to use `window.onload`, and `setInterval` inside `preload()`.
P5 documentation says *"If a preload function is defined, setup() will wait until any load calls within have finished."* Since you were continuously loading image using `loadImage()` inside `setInterval`, the `setup()` will never be called.

You can use a `setInterval` outside of `preload()` to update the `i`.

(I have used only 10 images for demo purpose)

Fixed Code:

```js
let faces = [];
let i = 0

function preload() {
  for (let k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    faces[k] = loadImage(`https://picsum.photos/450/150?random=${k}`)
  }
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

setInterval(() => {
  i++;
  if (i > 9) {
    i = 0;
  }
}, 400)

function draw() {
  background(256)
  image(faces[i], 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4kV7GkNv7QR7RX9YF/olywyIgIwNvfEe2nZtfyj73HdjCUkAfOBDbcuJ/cTaN04JKRnw1YG1wnUyNKMsNgg3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

Also, it is not advisable to load all 1000 images, because it will take huge amount of RAM, and may crash the browser. I didn't had any problems with *gaps in between images* (maybe bcoz of only 10 images, but with 1000 images, the most probable reason for gap would be RAM).